# Get consecutive capital letters using python regex

Tags: python

I want to get Consecutive words using python regex.
for example in the text :

```
"the United States of America has many big cities like New York and Los Angeles, and others like Atlanta"
```

the output should be

```
['United States of America','New York','Los Angeles']
```

Can someone help me ?
And FYI I'm already getting the output as 'United States' using the regex

```
[A-Z][a-z]+(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+
```

but I want it as 'United States of America'.The same goes for Johnson and Johnson.

Comment: `United States of America` does not have all consecutive capital letters. How should the regex engine know to match `of`?

Comment: Ya that's correct,but is it possible to put exception for the word 'of'.

Comment: Additionally, how does it know to match `Johnson and Johnson` but not `New York and Los Angeles`?

Comment: That's exactly the problem I'm facing.So I thought it would be good to start with 'of'.

Comment: @SoundarRaj what's the point of that? Then you're still stuck when you reach `'and'`.

Comment: Guess you all are right.It ain't gonna work. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Well, finally I sort of figured it out and it fits my need. Here's the pattern I finally ended up with that does the job.**

```
text = 'United States of America has many big cities like New York.'
pattern = '([A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)*(?:\s+[a-z]+)?(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)+)'
result = re.findall(pattern,text)
print result
['United States of America', 'New York']
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I've tackled such issues is by having some sort of an *exception list*. For example, if I find the word "United States", then the code should check if the next chars are "of" and parse until "America" (I hope that makes sense).  Speed and efficiency is something that needs to be closely considered when going about this method.  You can have a function that is O^n rather easily if your not careful.

PS
Why is this question getting so much down votes? It seems to be a valid question.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. And your solution might work for a predefined set of words, but I was looking for more of a generic solution. Say define a pattern that is case in-sensitive for words['of','and',...] that appears in the sentence.

Comment: I don't think there is anything generic per-se. Also, your "exception list" doesn't have to be predefined, I was just using that as an example to get your brain to come up with your own ideas. You could 1) search/find a word with caps, 2) check if ['of','and','the',...] is the next set of words, 3) if it is, then parse until the next word with a cap letter 4) else you probably don't have a match for your requirement. I would write some code out, but I can't focus my attention on this too much atm.